# Regex in XML using PHP: find certain value of a certain xml tag

Tags: regex, xml

I am trying to get the value of a certain attribute in a certain xml tag with regex but cant get it right, maybe someone has an idea how to do it?

The xml looks like this:

```
<OTA_PingRQ>
  <Errors>
    <Error Code="101" Type="4" Status="NotProcessed" ShortText="Authentication refused">Authentication : login failed</Error>
  </Errors>
</OTA_PingRQ>
```

and id like to match only the value of the Shorttext inside the Error tag.
in the end it should give me `"Authentication refused"` back.

What ive tried so far is using a lookbehind and lookahead, which doesnt let me take quantifiers with non fixed width. Like that `(?<=<Error .).*?(?=>)`.
Can someone tell me how to only match the value of the shorttext (inside the error tag)?

Comment: If available, you can use an xml parser instead.

Comment: im not allowed to sadly, i have to use a given method that uses regexpattern which i have to deliver to the method. the datatype is a string and not xml too even though its xml inside

Comment: Then you are stuck. At least, right now, with the details you shared, it is not possible to provide a solution that will work at all let alone a 100% working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the language you're using, i can give you the solution with PHP,  the regex remain the same in every language anyway.

Here is the regex you're looking for :

```
#\<Error Code\=\"[0-9]+\" Type\=\"[0-9]+\" Status\=\"NotProcessed\" ShortText\=\"([a-z 0-9]+)\"\>#is
```

**Concrete PHP use :**

```
$yourOriginalString = '
<OTA_PingRQ>
  <Errors>
    <Error Code="101" Type="4" Status="NotProcessed" ShortText="Authentication refused">Authentication : login failed</Error>
  </Errors>
</OTA_PingRQ>' ;

preg_match_all('#\<Error Code\=\"[0-9]+\" Type\=\"[0-9]+\" Status\=\"NotProcessed\" ShortText\=\"([a-z 0-9]+)\"\>#im', $yourOriginalString, $result) ;
print_r($result) ;
```

the regex function will return an array with :

```
   [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <Error Code="101" Type="4" Status="NotProcessed" ShortText="Authentication refused">
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Authentication refused
        )
```

[0] is the full match
[1] list the content in the matching capturing groups : each () set in your regex

**Some Regex explication :**

```
Type\=\"[0-9]+\"
```

Assume "Type" can change and be any numbers.

```
 ShortText\=\"([a-z 0-9]+)\"
```

Catch a string alphanumeric + space string. If you need some other stuffs, you can update like :

```
*[a-z 0-9\!\-]+*
```

catch ! and - too

```
#is
```

Are flags and ignore = caps and line break

Comment: thanks a lot! ill try right away when im able to. thanks for the good explanation

Comment: works like a charm, thanks!
edited title to better match your good answer